# Excel VBA: How to compare values of two cells?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I am trying to compare the values in two columns for consecutive rows. Specifically, I would like to check the value under Column B and Column C of each row with the one directly above it. And if it matches, perform some XYZ action.

I have the code below which I tried to use but it keeps throwing up errors.

Edit: I have provided a changed code below that does not have any of the typos my previous one did. I am still facing the same issue.

```
Sub MergeDupes2()


'Declaring variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Integer
Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 2
Dim column2ToMatch As Integer: column2ToMatch = 3


'Setting current worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


'Finding and calling the last row
lngRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


'Starting Loop
Do


'Finding Matching Values
If Range("C" & lngRow).Value = Range("C" & lngRow - 1).Value And Range("B" & lngRow).Value = Range("B" & lngRow - 1).Value Then


For i = 4 To 50


If ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = "" Then
   ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = ws.Cells(lngRow, i).Value

End If

Next i

End If


lngRow = lngRow - 1

Loop Until lngRow = 2


End Sub
```

This incorporates some of the suggestions below. Yet, I still have an error on this line. I have two versions of it and neither seem to work.

```
If ws.Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch).Value = ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch).Value And ws.Cells(lngRow, column2ToMatch).Value = ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, column2ToMatch).Value Then
```

```
If Range("C" & lngRow).Value = Range("C" & lngRow - 1).Value And Range("B" & lngRow).Value = Range("B" & lngRow - 1).Value Then
```

Comment: That was a typo in the post on my part, sorry - I've made the edits to reflect that. The actual code I was using did not have that second If, yet it didn't work. The same errors showed up.

Comment: OK, well you have a `Do` without a `Loop` and no loop as such so it would be endless anyway. Is there code missing from what you've posted?

Comment: Yes, there is a loop within the XYZ stuff - I'll add that to the post. Edit: I've added the whole code now.

Comment: WHat's the value of `lngRow` when it errors?

Comment: You need `lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row` - `Set` is only used for object variables.

Comment: Your code can't even compile. This needs to be `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding your intent, here are a few fixes that may help:

- Change `Set ws = ThisWorkbook("Sheet1")` to `Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")`
- Change `Set lngRow = ...` to just `lngRow = ...`
- Add `ws.` in front of `Cells(...` when you are comparing cell values

So full code would look like this:

```
Sub SortAndMergeDupes()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 2
Dim column2ToMatch As Integer: column2ToMatch = 3

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ActiveSheet
    lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
    Do
        If ws.Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch).Value = ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch).Value And ws.Cells(lngRow, column2ToMatch).Value = ws.Cells(lngRow - 1, column2ToMatch).Value Then
            For i = 4 To 50
                If .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value
                End If
            Next i
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop Until lngRow = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - looks like I made a lot of typos when copying my code. The first two fixes you suggest are already in my code - I did not type them up correctly here. The last one suggest, I tried but I still have the same error showing up.